# Prevent a Bloc event from being called multiple times within a set period of time

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm using a QRCode Scanner which triggers the same `Event` in my `Bloc` many times a second

In order to prevent spamming my API

-> I'd like **cancel / drop** all occurence of this event triggered within 5 seconds after the last one was called

---

Here is my [Bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) event :

```dart
    on<SearchWithQRCode>(_onSearchWithQRCode));
```

& here is for reference the presentation widget triggering the event

```dart
        MobileScanner(
          allowDuplicates: true,
          controller: cameraController,
          onDetect: (barcode, args) {
            if (barcode.rawValue == null) return;

            context.read<ScanQrCodeBloc>().add(
                  SearchWithQRUrl(qrUrl: barcode.rawValue!),
                );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Maybe BlocListner is better option

Comment: Feel free to add answer if you think there is better option, I will gladly upvote it : )

Comment: Thanks, but while it has been solved, I will pass for the setUp. I was referring to [bloclistener](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=bloclistener)

Comment: No problem , I don't see BlocListener having it's role in this scenario as events are triggered by a widget - but thanks for your input @YeasinSheikh : )

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you might be interested in [bloc_concurrency](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_concurrency) & [stream_transform](https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform)

Using this event transformer :

```dart
import 'package:stream_transform/stream_transform.dart';
import 'package:bloc_concurrency/bloc_concurrency.dart';

EventTransformer<E> throttleDroppable<E>(Duration duration) {
  return (events, mapper) {
    return droppable<E>().call(events.throttle(duration), mapper);
  };
}
```

like so :

```dart
  on<SearchWithQRUrl>(
      _onSearchWithQRUrl,
      transformer: throttleDroppable(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
    );
```

-> All **following calls** to this event occurring within the set **throttle duration** *(here 5 seconds)* **will be canceled**